# Is there a way to concatenate two general objects, like so?: (foo 'a 'b) => 'ab

Tags: common-lisp

Does anything like this exist? It seems like an elementary function, but I can't find anything like it.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with that? "concatenate" makes sense on string or sequences, and there are LISP functions to do that. It doesn't make sense on general objects. e.g. '(1 2)(3 4) is not even a legal expression.

Comment: I should have written two atoms, not two objects. Sorry about that.
I'd like something that behaves like [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list), except the output would be along the lines of '12345678 instead of '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8). But it doesn't even have to be that general, as I only want to append one atom to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Onlisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) (page 57, section 4.7, *Symbols and Strings*) has a solution that is a little more general:

```
(defun mkstr (&rest args)
  (with-output-to-string (s)
    (dolist (a args) (princ a s))))

(defun symb (&rest args)
  (values (intern (apply #'mkstr args))))
```

Using `symb` you can concatenate strings, symbols, numbers, whatever.

Comment: If you need this for hashing, [`sxhash`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_sxhash.htm) may be what you really need.

Comment: Using `symb` to get what you mention in your comment to the question is easy if you already have `flatten`: `(apply #'symb (flatten your-data))`. But this usage makes me wonder if you don't really want `sxhash` instead :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard One issue that bit me recently: if working with `:invert` as a value for `(readtable-case *readtable*)`, it's better to `string-upcase` the string before interning it. If you're not using `:invert` for the readtable case or not using `mksymb` for macros, just ignore this comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun concatoms (a b)
  (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name a) (symbol-name b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to generate new symbols. You can do this either with `intern` or with `make-symbol` (depending on if you want the symbol interned or not). However, it is also a signal that you're doing something that should require a bit more thinking, generating symbols from concatenation of the symbol-names of other symbols is seldom the best thing.

If you absolutely need to create new symbols, something like this ought to do the job:

```
(defun concatenate-symbols (a b &optional (package *package*))
  (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name a) (symbol-name b)) package))
```